# How do I re-integrate one branch merge that got caught up in a large git revert?

Tags: git

So lets say we have branches (from oldest to newest) First, Second, OG, Fourth, Fifth

These were all branched from, and then merged back into the Working branch in various order.

At some point recently, the range from newest (Fifth) to oldest (First) of the above commits was targeted for git revert.

In doing so, my merge (OG) was also reverted.

How do I put that one commit back while leaving the others out?

Answer (score 0):

You could rewrite the commits that make up `OG` that you want to apply again. This is so that git does not consider those revisions to have been merged ever... then you could merge it into the branch. Suppose that it's 2 commits one after the other that end up in `OG` that you want to merge again:

```
git checkout -b temp OG~2
# let's rewrite the 2 commits
git cherry-pick HEAD..OG # this will create 2 new commits just like the original 2... but they are not the same commits
# now you can merge this branch
git checkout fifth
git merge -m "Merging OG again" temp
```

That should work

Comment: Also, I see how this is supposed to work. . . new branch, pull old commits to new branch, merge new branch. All so we can get around git watching for old commits that it has already handled.

Comment: Good to know it makes sense.... it would be even better that it actually worked... and it would be _even better_ than both to get the upvote.